# Run Codeception Acceptance Test within two Integration Tests coded in simple PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit, integration-testing, codeception, acceptance-testing

Consider the following Integration test file extract based on `PHPUnit`:

```
...
/**
 * @return void
 */
public function test_first() {
    
    $this->assertTrue(true);
    
}

/**
 * @depends test_first
 * @return void
 */
public function test_acceptance() {

    $codecept = new Codecept();

    $codecept->run(
        suite: 'Acceptance',
        test : 'MyAcceptanceTests'
    );

    $ragg = $codecept->getResultAggregator();

    $this->assertTrue(
        condition: $ragg->wasSuccessfulAndNoTestIsUselessOrSkippedOrIncomplete()
    );
    
}

/**
 * @depends test_acceptance
 * @return void
 */
public function test_second() {
    
    $this->assertTrue(true);
    
}
...
```

I'm new to Codeception and the client wants to me to integrate browser-testing into their automated test stack. Precisely, they want to make sure that a specific page has the contents you should expect at the moment of a specific application within the state achieved in between two API requests (both tested via `test_first` and `test_second`, respectively, both working fine hence irrelevant for this question).

Using the syntax above, this seems to work, but I'm getting the warning:

```
1) /.../vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Codecept.php:257
Undefined array key "seed"
```

So it seems that this is not the proper way to launch a Codeception Acceptance test from within PHP, as the warning above indicates that the Codecept instance used for the test has not been properly initiated ? Note that this produces a warning if you use PHP 8.3. If you use any version older than that, the script fails with an error, as the first argument of `srand` (called in the line + codeception file of the warning) **must** apparently be an `int` in older PHP versions.

I know the docs technically recommend you to run Codeception tests via command line, but the `Codecept` class is there to run Codeception tests via PHP, no?

**UPDATE** :

I've been digging within the docs of the concerned `Codecept` and related file, and found that `srand()` is used to initiate the pseudo-random number generator within Codeception. I've not researched why this is done, so my approach may be the wrong solution. So before posting this as an answer, I'd like to know if it's a proper solution.

If I'm properly informed and `srand()` behaves in PHP as it [does in C](https://www.shiksha.com/online-courses/articles/rand-and-srand-functions-in-c-programming/#:%7E:text=The%20srand()%20function%20is,initialize%20the%20random%20number%20generator), `srand()` will seed the pseudo-random number generator with the current timestamp in PHP if its default value (in PHP that's `0`) is provided to its call. According to the `Codecept` constructor, the `options` property of a new instance gets initiated via:

`$this->options = $this->mergeOptions($options);`

The line of code causing the failure when running the Acceptance test via PHP, using the `Codecept` class, then is:

`srand($this->options['seed']);`

So I thought by simply providing the default solution for `srand()` within the `Codecept` constructor, this should solve the problem. Hence I replaced the line of my code above:

`$codecept = new Codecept();`

with:

`$codecept = new Codecept(['seed' => 0 ]);`

And this at least caused no more thrown errors / warnings. If this is the correct solution, what it does under the hood, and why `srand()` is even used in `Codecept::runSuite()`, no clue...??

Comment: You're looking at/for [shuffle](https://codeception.com/docs/AdvancedUsage#Shuffle), and I think how you do it is legit as an answer. The warning is perhaps noteworthy to report upstream, but before that would write the answer in a clear form and would clean up the question from it.